# ?キー名=値の部分が難しいです

Tags: javascript

ajaxの下記の部分がわかりません。

```
'helloAjax.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(document.fm.name.value), true);
```

#### 全体

```
<input type="text" name="name" size="15" /></label>
```

```
req.open('GET', 'helloAjax.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(document.fm.name.value), true);
```

#### 質問

?キー名=値&というJSの仕様のようですが、

```
'helloAjax.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(document.fm.name.value)
```

第二引数(文字列)
 ?キー名=値
 name="name"
属性名=属性の値
という対応をしているという事でよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 属性名=属性の値 という対応をしているという事でよいでしょうか？

はい、その通りです。
値のセットを二つ渡したい時は
?name1=value&name2=value2
となります

ただしこれはJSの仕様ではなくURIの仕様です。(RFC URI仕様に基づいたW3C規格)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string
(日本語版のwikipediaページが見当たりませんでした・・・)

encodeURIComponent()の部分はURI Encodingというものを行っております。
例えば値に"/"が入ってきたときはURLの一部として認識してしまうため"%2f"という文字列に変換されます。

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" size="15" /></label>

ありがとうございます。
すると'helloAjax.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(document.fm.name.value), true);
というのは、
.php?name='のnameがどの要素か識別するための識別子つまり
name="name"の値nameの部分。
cssでいうクラス名やID名に当たる部分。

よってここでname属性の値がnameの要素を取得して、
+以降がその要素の中にどんな文字列を入れるかを記載しているという事ですね。

Comment: 例のnameがkeyとvalueが同じ名前なので混乱気味ですが。「+以降がその要素の中にどんな文字列を入れるかを記載している」こちらご認識通りです。

Comment: つまり <input type="text" name="name" size="15" />が<input type="text" name="test" size="15" />になった場合
'helloAjax.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(document.fm.name.value), true);は
'helloAjax.php?test=' + encodeURIComponent(document.fm.name.value), true);
になるという事ですね。
ありがとうございました。